# MS Access : Macro Button to download Table from MySQL

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ado

I'm trying to create a button that connects to a MySQL DB and downloads tables (when clicked). I created the following Macro :

```
Sub ADO_conn_Click()
Dim conn As New Connection
Dim rs As New Recordset

    strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=test1.server.net:63306" & _
    "User Id=admin;Password=test"

    conn.Open (strcon)

    qry = "SELECT * FROM Employee"
    rs.Open qry, conn, adOpenKeyset

    rs.Close
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

Source : http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/12/how-to-connect-to-access-database-excel-macro/ - i also did the prerequisites. When I try to run the macro, I get the following error : "Compile Error - Invalid use of New Keyword" . Any Ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you tried replacing the `Dim conn As New Connection` with `Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection` and same for the recordset?

Comment: You are using the MS Access an OLEDB connection to connect to MySQL. You need to use a MySQL driver connection. Install the MySQL [ODBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) and connect wth [ADO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-programming-vb-ado.html). MS Access is a file level database (data source points to a directory file path). MySQL is a server level database (source points to server).

Answer (score 0):

in `strcon` between your second and third line there is no space. Is the word 'user' meant to be apart of the data source as in... `Source=test1.server.net:63306User` ?

I think you need a semicolon so try the following...
I also think that you might have to declare `strcon` as a string variable.

```
dim strcon as string

strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=test1.server.net:63306;" & _
"User Id=admin;Password=test"
```

> EDIT

I have noticed that `qry` is not declared as a string either, you may need to do the same with this as I suggested with `strconn`.

`dim qry as string`